# I getting an incorrect number of dimensions error while trying to calculate the standard deviation of various rows of a csv file

Tags: r, csv, compiler-errors, dimensions, standard-deviation

I have a .csv file whose standard deviations I need to calculate, which contains information for 4 controls and 4 test samples. The file contains over 5000 rows that are data points at different times. As all data are not of the same length, I have truncated the file to the 1st 2500 rows such that there are no N/A values. The code is as follows:

```
#row means
library(genefilter)
delta = read.csv("/filename.csv", nrows = 2500)

mn1 = rowMeans(delta[,1:4]) # controls
mn2 = rowMeans(delta[,5:8]) # test

s1 = rowSds(mn1[,1:4]) # controls
s2 = rowSds(mn2[,5:8]) # test
```

The program calculates the mean perfectly, but gives me an error when trying to calculate the standard deviation:

```
Error in mn1[, 1:4] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Help on what is going wrong and how to correct it would be appreciated.

As suggested, here is the file: [.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5q5JCErdOG7SERRVUwzXzdFcmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide a reproductible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you calculate the std. deviation from `mn1` and `mn2` - not from your data. This should work (couldn't install the `genefilter` package):

`s1 = rowSds(delta[,1:4]) # controls
s2 = rowSds(delta[,5:8]) # test`